# Workfront (Attask) API: Is there a way to clear/reset 'commitDate' on a task?

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Pretty much exactly the title, I'm wondering if there is a way to clear/reset the `commitDate` field of a task. For example, I'm trying the following request to the API. I get no errors, but when I query the task again it shows no changes to the `commitDate` field.

```
https://thecompany.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v7.0/task/1234567890?method=put&updates={"taskConstraint": "MSO", "commitDate":"","constraintDate":"2017-08-07"}&fields=commitDate,plannedCompletionDate,actualCompletionDate,constraintDate&sessionID=12345
```

I've also tried all other variations of this request that I could think of, including using `null` as the `commitDate` value, but they all return the same results. No error. No change to `commitDate` field.

The only thing I can think of is that possibly there is something the actual *task* is missing. The task I'm testing on is a dummy task, so maybe I missed something while creating it, but it does have a `commitDate`, so I'm not sure what else I'd be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

commitDate is set when an assignment is accepted and is based upon the accepting user's workload at the time of acceptance. You may update the commitment date to another value but you cannot have an empty commit date unless the task is actually complete.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `commitDate` can only be cleared when there is an `actualCompletionDate` assigned to the task. Once the task had an `actualCompletionDate` assigned I was able to reset the `commitDate`. I'm not sure why that is required, but it works.