# Workfront API: What is necessary to clear/reset a task's commitDate?

Tags: attask, workfront-api

This is in response to my [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567797/5750392).

I need to use the WorkFront API to reset `commitDate`'s for tasks. The only way I've found that this is possible (as documented in the link above) is if the task has an `actualCompletionDate` assigned. This relationship doesn't make sense to me. Is there any other way to reset a task's `commitDate` date? Does it *have* to have an `actualCompletionDate` assigned? I haven't been able to get it to work any other way, but maybe (hopefully) I'm just missing something.

Comment: This seems to be substantially the same as your previous question. Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @BrianR - Agreed possible duplicate. Figured better to ask a new question than to append onto another.